# Android display English digits while phone language is Arabic?

Tags: android, text

My phone language is Arabic.

In my application the EditText displays the digits in English (OK) but the TextView displays the digits in arabic!

How Can I force the TextView to display digits in English despite the phone language?

Comment: Are you using localized string values? Provide some code

Comment: Set an english only font for that text view?  BTW, a picture may help here-  at least in the US we call 1,2,3,4... arabic numerals so your question can be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use values-*country*, like: values-en for english or values-nl for dutch or values-fr for french and add a strings.xml with the values you need